# WP 7 - HttpWebRequest Encoding ISO-8859-2

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-7, encoding

I have this code:

```
    private void HandleWebResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        WebRequestState state = (WebRequestState)asyncResult.AsyncState;

        HttpWebRequest request = state.Request;
        string url = request.RequestUri.ToString();
        state.Response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
        string absolutePath = state.Response.ResponseUri.AbsolutePath;


        if (state.Response != null)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(state.Response.GetResponseStream(),Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                sb.Append(reader.ReadLine());
            ...
```

And I have web page with encoding ISO-8859-2, but WP7 doesn´t support this encoding. How can I convert this encoding to another? Or do you have tips how to bypass this problem? Thx for every advice.

Comment: If iso-8859-2 isn't supported, you can try with iso-8859-16 and see the result. There is a lot of similarities between these two character sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [Silverlight Encoding Generator](http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator) to get the encoding you need!